# Pad an Integer with 0 mid string

Tags: db2

I have a table with a column that stores `ID` values (integers) that require a *padding* with 0s (zeroes) in the middle. I can *pad* left or right but, how do I pad in the middle?

For example:

- `4001` = `40001`
- `4123` = `40123`
- `4000` = `40000`

So, any number *4XXX* becomes *40XXX*.

**Comment interactions**

Question:

> To clarify, once the values of the relevant column get the *padding*, are they meant to:
>
> - be stored permanently **or**
> - to be temporarily computed only (e.g., the *padding* serves display purposes only)?

Response:

They should be stored permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are indeed `INTEGER`s, it should be simply

```
UPDATE 
  yourtable 
SET yourcolumn = 
    FLOOR(yourcolumn/1000) * 10000 + MOD(yourcolumn, 1000)
```

Comment: If DB2 is similar to SQL Server in that it uses integral division when both operands are integers, then you don't even need FLOOR.

Comment: @AndriyM you're right, of course, but explicit `FLOOR` shows the logic. I'm not a big fan of cryptic code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know db2 I have done it in sql server, hope it helps:

```
--4001 = 40001
--4123 = 40123
--4000 = 40000

--so any number 4XXX becomes 40XXX


declare @t table (
   number_to_convert int not null primary key clustered)

DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @Z INT

SELECT @I=0
SELECT @Z=2000

WHILE @I < @Z BEGIN
  insert into @t(number_to_convert) VALUES (4000 + @I)
  SELECT @I = @I + 1
END 

select number_to_convert,
       number_converted= CAST (((number_to_convert/1000)  * CASE WHEN (number_to_convert % 1000) < 10  THEN 1000 ELSE 
                                            CASE WHEN (number_to_convert % 1000) < 100 THEN 100  ELSE 
                                                       10 END END ) AS VARCHAR) + CAST ((number_to_convert % 1000) AS VARCHAR)
 from @t
```

result set (partial list):

[image]